# Function return a list of values that could only be get asynchronously

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous

I'd like to write this function:

```
function getResults(nums){
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = nums.length; i < len; i++){
        var num = nums[i];
        ajaxGet("http://xxx.com/" + num, function(data){
            results.push(data);
        });
    }
    return results;
}    
var results = getResults([12, 22, 34]);
```

as you can see, because `ajaxGet` is asynchronous, this won't work. How could I do this properly?

Comment: The only problem I see in your code is: results.push[data];
 -> results.push(data);

Comment: @ItayMoav Oh that's a typo, thanks. do you think the code above could get the correct result?

Comment: @ItayMoav: Looking at porn could also be a problem.

Comment: Looking at Porn is never a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the array using a callback, and call the callback when you receive the last response.  (note that responses will not be received in order)

```
function getResults(nums, callback) {
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = nums.length; i < len; i++){
        var num = nums[i];
        ajaxGet("http://xxx.com/" + num, function(data){
            results.push(data);
            if (results.length === nums.length)
                callback(results);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also tell Ajax to run synchronously

```
$.ajax({async: false});
var results = getResults();
$.ajax({async: true});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can set the async flag to false:

```
function getResults(nums){
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = nums.length; i < len; i++){
        var num = nums[i];
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://xxx.com/" + num}, 
            async: flase,
            success: function(data){
                results.push(data);
            }
        });
    }
    return results;
}    
var results = getResults([12, 22, 34]);
```

But if you're doing it this way then your approach is wrong. Go with [SLaks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8959140/465546) instead.

[**`jQuery.ajax()` API page**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var allresults;

function getResults(nums){
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = nums.length; i < len; i++){
        var num = nums[i];
        ajaxGet("http://xxx.com/" + num, function(data){
            results.push(data);
            if(results.length == nums.length){
                 resume(results);
            }
        });
    }

}

getResults([12, 22, 34]);

function resume(results){
   allresults =  results;
   ....
   ....
}
```

Like others said, use if you are not using jQuery